# Git clone ssh access windows drive

Tags: git, ssh, clone

I need to clone a git project which reside on windows server `d:\GitRepos\test.git`.
I am logging in through ssh under Administrator on the server `d:\cygwin\home\Administrator\t2.git`

when I do git clone from my local:

```
git clone ssh://Administrator@host.com/~/t2.git ./t2.git ==> this is ok
```

how can I clone test.git which reside on `d:\GitRepos\test.git`?

I've tried:

```
git clone ssh://Administrator@host.com/d/GitRepos/test.git ./test.git ==>fail
git clone ssh://Administrator@host.com/cygdrive/d/GitRepos/test.git ./test.git ==>fail
```

Any suggestion please?

Nevermind: 
I can access it with

```
git clone ssh://Administrator@host.com/../../GitRepos/test.git ./test.git
```

provided your Admin home is 2 folders deep.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the server is running the sshd in cygwin, you need to use the cygwin mappings that map the windows drives to the cygwin/unix file space, usually `/cygdrive/d` for `D:\`.

so you should be able to go

```
git clone ssh://Administrator@host.com/cygdrive/d/GitRepos/test.git test.git
```

Comment: tried that git clone ssh://Administrator@host.com/cygdrive/d/GitRepos/test.git test.git,
but still no good.